# Find and replace values within ranges in excel

Tags: excel, loops, excel-formula

I have an array in excel that looks something like this, though much larger:

```
A      B    C       D         E      F        G
0      0    0       0       2.78    2.48    2.11
0      0    0       3.11    2.94    2.78    2.15
0      0    0       2.72    2.7     2.2     2.15
0    1.68   2.44    2.29    2.13    0        0
1.89 1.97   2.43    2.07    0       0        0
```

I'm trying to find all the values within an interval, then replace them with a different value according to a chart that looks like the one below. The values in the first row are the limits of an interval, and the second row represents the value I would like to insert into the array above. For example, the value in cell A5= 1.89. 1.89 falls between 1.8 and 1.9 so according to the chart below I would like the output to be 19.9192.

```
A       B         C        D         E         F          G  ........>

1.6    1.7       1.8      1.9        2        2.1        2.2         2.3       2.4       2.5      2.6       2.7      2.8        2.9       3      3.1             3.2
19.51  19.721   19.9192  20.1088    20.2903  20.4644    20.6318     20.7928  20.9484    21.0986  21.2441    21.3849  21.5214    21.654   21.7829     21.9083    22.0304
```

In terms of finding the values, I've tried the following :

```
 =AND(A1 > Lower limit ,A1< Upper limit)
```

And using the Lower/ Upper limits as neighboring cells in the chart. For example,

```
 =AND (A1> A10, A<A11)
```

which returns a value of either FALSE or TRUE depending of if the cell A1 is within the specified interval. I realize this isn't quite right but I'm not sure how to proceed. If its TRUE, I'm not sure how I can then insert the value I want based on the second chart - for example 19.9192 if the value was between 1.8 and 1.9, and if FALSE, I'm not sure how I can than move on to check the next interval and keep checking intervals until the right one is found an the cell is replaced appropriately. I think a loop might be needed, but I've not worked much with excel and haven't been able to get any syntax right to try it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A second look at your reference data, the format is in precision of 0.1. Whereas the input data is of 0.01 and 0.1. another condition is you take the lower bound of the difference. Thus, I would roundup the value 1st, then query the ref table using it. eg. 1.89 > convert to 1.8 > look for 1.8 pair value > retrieve value.

in I2 enter :

`=IFERROR(INDEX($11:$11,MATCH(INT(A1*10)/10,$10:$10,0)),"")`  and drag it until O6.

+----[formula breakdown:]----+

round the number to 0.1 precision > INT(A1*10)/10

look for 1.8 position in the selection > match()

retrieve the value from the position identified > index()

hope that helps. (: